# Preventing the Function to run in javascript in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am trying to load a url in iframe which i dont have complete control . It loads the Javascript  which has a Document.CreateElement and it has some reference to the window object which is failing because an iframe is not allowed to access the window. So i want to override the implementation of the function,So the function which i have written will run instead of the one written by the other website

Comment: If the iframe you're trying to access isn't being loaded from the same server your page is loaded from you can't do this -- look up the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

it can't be done if the other website is not on your domain

Comment: actually, it's not just that.  the port, protocol and server must match.  so even its just from the same domain it won't work necessarily.